# Erro "1052 Column in where clause is ambiguous"?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou com problemas na realização de um sistema. Estou fazendo um join e o seguinte erro aparece:

> Error Number: 1052 Column 'id_doador' in where clause is ambiguous
>   SELECT * FROM `doacao` JOIN `doador` ON `doacao`.`id_doador` =
>   'doador`.`id_doador`WHERE`id_doador` = '1'

Segue abaixo o meu método no model.

```
    public function minhasDoacoes(){
    $id_doador = $this->session->userdata('id_doador');
    $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('doacao')
    ->join('doador', 'doacao.id_doador = doador.id_doador')
    ->where('id_doador', $id_doador);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Comment: Olá tudo bem? Não seria `->where('doador.id_doador', $id_doador);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `where` inclua o nome da tabela (`doador.id_doador`) igual nesse exemplo:

```
public function minhasDoacoes(){
    $id_doador = $this->session->userdata('id_doador');
    $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('doacao')
    ->join('doador', 'doacao.id_doador = doador.id_doador')
    ->where('doador.id_doador', $id_doador);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

o problema é que ele não sabe qual `id_doador` está fazendo o `where` por ter dois campos com o mesmo nome. Nada impede que seja colocado `doacao.id_doador` nesse caso trazendo o mesmo resultado.